# Where to put link to html5shiv.js? Before css <styles> or with other <script> tags?

Tags: html, css, html5shiv

As I understand html5shiv.js file "teaches" browsers like IE to process CSS3 properly:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Where should I include it - before styles tag or at the bottom of the page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Where to put this link to html5shiv? -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="scripts/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="some.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <!--html content -->

    <!-- scripts should be loaded after DOM is constructed -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // some scripts here..
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "As I understand html5shiv.js file "teaches" browsers like IE to process CSS3 properly"  — It doesn't. It allows <IE9 to recognize elements added in HTML 5 for the purposes of styling (with CSS 1). The correct place to put it is: Nowhere. Not even Microsoft supports versions of IE that old any more, not even for security updates.

Comment: But to answer your question, put it as the first thing in the HEAD where you have it now

Comment: @Quentin a LOT of the developers at dotJS yesterday had to support IE9 because their corporate bosses tell them to. It is not that long ago my office was standardised on IE8.

Comment: @Quentin What Microsoft supports is irrelevant. I too have customers who are bound to Windows XP running IE 8 & 9! I can't force a large company to update all their clients. So what you gave is an ideological nice but completely useless and sarcastic comment.

Comment: Thank You for responses! I read a book that was written few years ago :)  Want to make my code supported by all browsers, because work with intranet and they update slowly(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get started with a new tool or code snippet or library and you don't understand it at a first glance, **you really should start reading the manual!**

> Include the HTML5 shiv in the  of your page in a conditional comment and **after any stylesheets**.

See: https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv

Comment: Ahha. Thank You! So it should be in head, but after css styles